# How to change the styles Dynamically in aggrid with an external button click?

Tags: angular, angular8, ag-grid

cellClassRules: {'makeRed':'!this.flag'}

i want this flag variable based on a button click and then it should make changes in the grid

In Angular 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On click of the button, you could set a variable in your component class to true. Something like :

xyz.component.html
`<button (click) = "onButtonClick()"> My button </button>`

xyz.component.ts

```
public buttonClicked = false;

onButtonClick()
{
   this.buttonClicked = true;
}
```

Then in your column defs, you can do something like :

```
cellClassRules: {'makeRed':this.buttonClicked}
```

where makeRed is a CSS class that defines your custom properties.

Note: If you wish to do this for a button toggled behavior, then you'd need to do something like :

```
onButtonClick()
{
   this.buttonClicked = this.buttonClicked ? !this.buttonClicked : this.buttonClicked
}


cellClassRules: {
'makeRed':this.buttonClicked,
'makeGreen': !this.buttonClicked,
}
```

Comment: Yes @AkshAy Agrawal your answer is correct and we have to add the grid refresh() method in the click().Thanks a ton